# GIMP: Permission Denied error when saving with file_png_save2, but not when saving through File->Export

Tags: python, gimp, gimpfu

I'm trying to write a script to automate some things for a project I'm working on, and one of the steps is saving a file as a png. I'm using file_png_save2. When running the script, it errors out with a "Permission Denied" message. However, I can save files to the same folder with no issue if I go through File->Export.
I'm running Gimp 2.10 on Windows 11. Here is the code for the script so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
 
from gimpfu import *

baseURL = "C:\\Users\\MyID\\OneDrive\\Pictures\\ScriptTest\\"
 
def char_img_164(image, drawable, imgid):
    pdb.gimp_edit_copy(image.layers[0])
    newImg = pdb.gimp_edit_paste_as_new_image()
    pdb.gimp_image_scale(newImg, 164, 164)
    dispImg = pdb.gimp_display_new(newImg)
    layer = pdb.gimp_image_merge_visible_layers(newImg, CLIP_TO_IMAGE)
    pdb.file_png_save2(newImg, layer, baseURL + "test1",imgid+".png",0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 
register(
   "char_img_164",
   "Image test",
   "Test script",
   "MyID",
   "MyID",
   "2023",
   "<Image>/Image/ScriptTest/IMG164",
   "*",
   [
       (PF_STRING, "imgid", "Enter ID", "hello")
       ],
   [],
   char_img_164)
 
main()
```

One error message reads:
An error occurred running python-fu-char_img_164
RuntimeError: Could not open 'C:\Users\MyID\OneDrive\Pictures\ScriptTest\test1' for writing: Permission denied

There is also a GIMP message which reads:
Calling error for procedure 'file-png-save2':
Could not open 'C:\Users\arcad\MyID\Pictures\ScripTest\test1' for writing: Permission denied

Some more attempted troubleshooting:

There was nothing related to the Python interpreter in the security log.

I tried having it write to another disk (E://ScriptText/test1), but got the same error.

I checked the file permissions for the ScriptText and test1 folders, and they're both able to be written to.

I tried running the Python interpreter as Administrator, but still got that error.

Another Edit:

After some more experimenting, it looks like I've found a solution. It may not be the best solution, and feel free to tell me if it isn't, but it is at least *a* solution. I went into the "Properties" tab for the folder where the image was supposed to be saved and added write permissions for the "Guests" object. I guess either Gimp or Python was running as a guest.

Comment: Show the full error message please

Comment: RuntimeError: Could not open 'C:\Users\MyID\OneDrive\Pictures\ScriptTest\test1' for writing: Permission denied

Comment: There are two error dialogs. The other one says:
Calling error for procedure 'file-png-save2':
Could not open 'C:\Users\MyID\OneDrive\Pictures\ScriptTest\test1' for writing: Permission denied

Comment: Please edit your post to include the whole error message, verbatim.